# Pyinstaller executable could not find a distribution that was included

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Here's my system info:

```
35 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.6
36 INFO: Python: 3.7.2
41 INFO: Platform: Darwin-19.6.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
```

I've been trying to generate a Python (Flask) executable using Pyinstaller to be used in an app. However, when I package the executable and run it, it will throw this:

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pyonfleet' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

This dependency already exists in my virtual environment, and from the debug import logs of Pyinstaller, I can see these lines:

```
import onfleet # PyInstaller PYZ
import onfleet.onfleet # PyInstaller PYZ
import 'onfleet.request' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fbda00ab5f8>
import 'onfleet.endpoint' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fbda00ab5f8>
import onfleet.config # PyInstaller PYZ
import 'onfleet.config' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fbda00ab5f8>
import 'onfleet.onfleet' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fbda00ab5f8>
import 'onfleet' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fbda00ab5f8>
```

I've tried adding a hook as suggested here: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4833 but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Have you tried the latest PyInstaller 4.0 - this has hooks updated more frequently than the PyInstaller releases.

Comment: @barny I just did update to Pyinstaller 4.0 and still ran into the same issue

Comment: Did you ask onfleet support about using PyInstaller?

Comment: @barny I ended up finding that PyInstaller somehow messes up the dependencies and it fails when it uses `pkg_resources`. Specifically when `pyonfleet` calls it:

`"User-Agent": "pyonfleet-" + pkg_resources.require("pyonfleet")[0].version`

I commented out the line and the packaging worked, although still unsure why and what PyInstaller did there...